# Ansible vaulted variables with quotes in it

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible 2.4.
I can't get following ansible-playbook to run:

`test.yml`

```
---
- hosts: "localhost"
  become: no

  vars:
    foo_withsinglequote: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          39313737636336313832376165636465346162366333663137373165363662316263336166393666
          3566643732663063386333303638633962363863306463610a643931396636613361353165653265
          38376630313939626637623538613432373336646663636563623062636238313731326263336263
          3138643931323662620a336534383964663562353162393930613965386465616630363335326138
          3431
    foo_withdoublequote: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          64633863363838326664323238313866616161313937323563636430326432393638336334303336
          3533653339663438356238613937336466623834666537630a646139643033653237353262616662
          30643732313861373130633036346361663130326332303932616433643761633739306137333237
          6263653365386132620a633738663336313532366637613533313361646339623137393461383363
          3332

  tasks:
   - name: Echo foo_withsinglequote
     command: echo "{{ foo_withsinglequote }}"
   - name: Echo foo_withdoublequote
     command: echo "{{ foo_withdoublequote }}"
```

To generate the vault variables I used following:

```
$ echo 123 > vlt.txt
$ ansible-vault --vault-password-file=vlt.txt encrypt_string "abc\"def"
$ ansible-vault --vault-password-file=vlt.txt encrypt_string "abc\'def"
```

To run the playbook:

```
$ ansible-playbook --vault-password-file=vlt.txt test.yml
```

This gives following error:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ValueError: No closing quotation
>
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_8uz23O/ansible_module_command.py\", line 213, in \n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_8uz23O/ansible_module_command.py\", line 182, in main\n    args = shlex.split(args)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py\", line 279, in split\n    return list(lex)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py\", line 269, in next\n    token = self.get_token()\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py\", line 96, in get_token\n    raw = self.read_token()\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py\", line 172, in read_token\n    raise ValueError, \"No closing quotation\"\nValueError: No closing quotation\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}

How can I quote the vaulted variables correctly? Because I don't know in advance, if the vaulted variables will contain single or double quotes.

Comment: I thought I explained in the answer that your problem has nothing to do with Ansible Vault, but quoting the variable... yet you edited the answer to expand the Vault-part.

Comment: Yes and I corrected the question according to your suggestion.

Comment: No, you have not. Search how many times the word "vault" appears in your question. Also check if this number decreased from before the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem description, despite being well written, unfortunately wrongly attributes the problem to Ansible Vault.

In fact, the problem you reported, comes simply from trying to execute the task which effectively becomes:

```
- command: echo abc"def
```

Ansible Vault plays no role in causing this problem -- if you defined the variable directly with `foo: abc\"def` you'd get the same error message.

---

The solution is simply to quote the string in the `echo` command:

```
- command: echo '{{ foo }}'
```

---

Other than that you can use [`quote` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7), but for Vault-protected variable you need to first set a static fact:

```
- set_fact:
    bar: "{{ foo }}"
- command: echo {{ bar|quote }}
```

---

<sup>Finally, the simplest solution to the underlying problem is: do not use special characters in passwords. Increase the length instead.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I updated the question, because I don't know if the variable will contain double or single quotes in advance.

Comment: Changing the question after getting an answer will get you lots of friends in StackExchange community.

Comment: I had the variable quoted in my original script but the quotes got somehow lost when I made this minimum example.

Comment: I will try the solution with set fact. Thx

Comment: This comment: "*I had the variable quoted in my original script but the quotes got somehow lost when I made this minimum example.*" reads: "I'm sloppy and I'm proud of it, and if you spend your time because of my sloppiness, it's your problem, you're just a sucker". I don't know if you intended it, but this is what the recipient understands. That's what communication is about. You could have remained silent.

Comment: Hmm, before your edit the question was may except the title pretty clear.

Comment: Sorry, if you want to communicate something, please try to do it more clearly. I can’t make any sense of what you wanted to say by “*Hmm, before your edit the question was may except the title pretty clear.*” Please point to [the exact edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47339359/revisions) and explain what happened because of that edit.

Comment: "*And what you read out of a normal comment is just you.*" -- yes it's me -- if I asked for help and someone spent a second helping me, then announcing "I did it before you, I just somehow forgot to tell you" is blatantly rude. If somebody caught me saying so, I would rather search for a place to hide. I think this is the right logic and I stand for it.